# ERC20 decimals in smart contract

Tags: solidity, erc-20, smart-contract-wallets, solidity-0.8.x

How will I tell the EVM and wallet about the decimal?
Do they automatically read it from the constructor function???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explained [here](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L87), the `decimals` in an ERC20 token are just for representation to the user. The EVM has nothing to do with it. A wallet that recognizes ERC20 tokens and knows how many decimals a token has (by calling `decimals()` function), can represent the number of tokens to the user in a more readable way.

You know that Solidity does not support floating point numbers, so we use to represent a floating point number in a `uint` by dedicating some of the numbers to consider them as 'decimals'.

For example, if you have a custom token that you need to allow 2 decimals of precision, then you could represent the number `5.34` as `534` in Solidity and have a state variable or function `decimals()` that returns the value `2` to let us know that `534` has actually 2 decimal numbers which are the last ones and we could then show the user in the frontend `5.34`.

Check the documentation of the OpenZeppelin `ERC20` `decimals()` function: https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol#L87

Comment: Thank you for answering,
So if I am writing my own smart contract for a simple token without using any OpenZeppelin contract, do I need to create a decimal() function, or creating a decimal variable in the constructor is enough for it???

Comment: I got the answer. Thank you, Jeremy.

Comment: Public variables actually _are_ functions. So, if your `decimals` variable is public, you don't need to. If it's private however, you need to create a getter function.

Comment: As Foxxxey mentioned, the Solidity compiler creates a getter function for public state variables with the same name of the state variable. Probably athe OpenZeppelin ERC20 implementation uses function to add the `virtual` modifier so contracts extending from it can `override` that function and return a different `decimals` value.

Comment: why is it that I can't call `Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider(url)).eth.contract(...).decimals()`?